# Hibernate and which database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am wondering about the databases-on-Hibernate in general.

Should I be particularly concerned with "which database" to use Hibernate on?
Would I have to give up on some features of a DB package just by using it with Hibernate? 
Should I get into more trouble with using DB, say "XYZ", just because there are some configuration or usage concerns with using Hibernate on XYZ and the two don't work so very well together? I am thinking about MySQL for Hibernate. From what I see, the Hibernate integration/setup is pretty straightforward and Hibernate is giving a large number of options on the DBs to choose from. But then, are things so smooth still when I get deep into their use-together?

New to Hibernate, looking to figure for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is nothing more than ORM, if Hibernate makes you to change to use different DB, then I would drop that ORM, but hibernate most likely supports all common db, See [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2?_sscc=t). Selection of database much more important than selecting ORM for that. Hibernate configuration is straightforward for most of the db(I haven't checked hibernate with all dbs). With mysql you may have trouble with transactions, it is not because of hibernate, it is because of the engine that mysql is using(I believe MyIsam does not support and InnoDB does support transactions). So select whatever db fits best and use with hibernate. Do not change db because of hibernate.

Comment: this is for self-learning Hibernate-- db at the back isn't much of an issue. i've been looking for one that would leave me alone w/HN alone, so just about any of them would do i guess. thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. If it is self learning go with mysql, easy, lightweight, open source, many many reasons.